# How to convert Sql Query into Laravel with some simple procedures

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Its a nested Sql query which i wanted to convert into laravel.
Please help!

```
SELECT party_name,party_electorial_sign,party_flag 
FROM parties 
where party_name IN 
        (SELECT n.CANDIDATE_PARTY 
        FROM voters V, na_candidates N 
        WHERE voter_cnic= 'nic' AND V.NA_CONSTITUENCY=N.NA_CONSTITUENCY)
```

Comment: Any part you're having particular difficulty with?

Comment: can you share the table structure

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this will help you.

```
Party::query()->whereIn('party_name',DB::raw('SELECT n.CANDIDATE_PARTY 
        FROM voters V, na_candidates N 
        WHERE voter_cnic= 'nic' AND V.NA_CONSTITUENCY=N.NA_CONSTITUENCY'))
```